# Get the string length of <a> inside an <li>

Tags: jquery, html

I need to set the width of `<li>`  based on the maximum string length of the element from the `<a>` which is child of `<li>`.

```
<ul id="hi">
    <li class="">
        <a >Maintenance</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a >Query</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a >Approve Level </a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a >Reverse</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a >Refund Charges</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a > Update After </a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a > Update After  Update After  Update After  Update</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I just want to get the largest string width of the `<a>` (in the above case last `<a>` and set the width of all `<li>` through the script. Please give me a solution

Comment: This is definately one of those questions, where you need to explain why are you trying to do this, because then we can explain the correct way of doing what you want to do. What you want to do is just wrong. Namely, in that while it could be done, you would need to use Javascript, and secondly, it is just stupid. Use correct CSS and display blocks, to achieve what you want.. but firstnly, why are you trying to do this? What do you hope to achieve?

Comment: What @Laykes said. Also, if you want the longest line, it may not be the same as the largest number of characters. For example, all those multiple spaces will collapse to a single space. You'd be better off measuring the `width` of the `li`s with jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This jQuery snippet will save the length of the longest string to `max`:

```
var length, max = 0;
$('#hi li a').each(function(){
    length = $(this).text().length;
    max = length > max ? length : max;
});
```

Example can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3vNE7/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var len, maxLen = 0;
$("#hi a").each(function(){
  len = $(this).text().length;
  if(len > maxLen)
    maxLen = len;
});

$("#hi li").css("width", len*10);//Set the apprpriate multiplier here or some base width, but now you have the largest lenth here
```

Comment: Why not assigning `$(this).text().length` to variable? Would be much better practice.

Comment: Becuase I have to set only the largest length.

Comment: You didn't understand what I mean.. executing `$(this).text().length` takes some time - repeating this action twice is not efficient. If you assign it to variable then you only execute it once, which is more efficient and better practice.

Comment: If I was going to go down the JS/CSS route, I would have just checked the domNode width, and not bothered with width.

Comment: @nav - I answered long back and you didn't accepted mine thats not fair :)